# Function Satisfying given Equalities

Tags: polynomials

We wish to find a function $f(x,y)$ such that the following equalities hold,

$f(-1,0)=1$

$f(-1,1)=0$

$f(1,1)=1$

$f(1,0)=0$

$f(0,0)=1$

$f(0,1)=1$

I am unsure whether one can establish a systems of equations to fit these points to a polynomial or if that will be insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a polynomial of the form $a+bx+cy+dx^2+exy+fy^2$.

The function $f(x,y)=1-x/2-x^2/2+xy$ should work.